# How to get file path of a add_static_view() in Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

When I am adding a `static view` like this:

```
cfg = config.Configurator(...)
cfg.add_static_view(name='static', path='MyPgk:static')

# And I want to add a view for 'favicon.ico'.
cfg.add_route(name='favicon', pattern='/favicon.ico')
cfg.add_view(route_name='favicon', view='MyPgk.views.mymodule.favicon_view')
```

I am trying to add that favicon.ico annoying default path of `/favicon.ico` called by the browser if it's undefined in the webpage. I would like to use the example at http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/files.html and modify it to have:

```
def favicon_view(request, cache=dict()):
    if (not cache):
        _path_to_MyPkg_static = __WHAT_GOES_HERE__
        _icon = open(os.path.join(_path_to_MyPkg_static, 'favicon.ico')).read()
        cache['response'] = Response(content_type='image/x-icon', body=_icon)
    return cache['response']
```

Since, I can't really define the `_here` proposed in the example, how can I make it dependent to `request` to get the actual full path at runtime? Or do I really have to deal with:

```
_here = os.path.dirname(__file__)
_path_to_MyPkg_static = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(_here), 'static')
```

and having to be careful when I decide to refactor and put the view in another pkg or subpackage, or where-ever?

Something equivalent to `request.static_path()` but instead of getting the `url path`, to actually get a directory path:

`request.static_file_path('static')` -> `/path/to/site-packages/MyPkg/static`

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `pkg_resources` module to make paths that are relative to Python modules (and thus, independent of the module that retrieves them). For example:

```
import pkg_resources
print pkg_resources.resource_filename('os.path', 'static/favicon.ico')
# 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\static\\favicon.ico'
```

Just substitute `os.path` with whatever module that is the parent of your static files.

**EDIT**: If you need to remember that `'static'` route mapped to `'MyPkg:static'`, then the easiest way is to save it in some dictionary in the first place:

```
STATIC_ROUTES = {'static': 'MyPkg:static'}
for name, path in STATIC_ROUTES.iteritems():
    cfg.add_static_view(name=name, path=path)
```

and then simply retrieve the path:

```
static_path = STATIC_ROUTES['static']
package, relative_path = static_path.split(':')
icon_path = pkg_resources.resource_filename(
    package, os.path.join(relative_path, 'favicon.ico'))
```

If that's impossible, though (e.g. you don't have access to the `cfg` object), you *can* retrieve this path, it's just quite painful. Here's a sample function that uses undocumented calls (and so may change in future Pyramid versions) and ignores some additional settings (like `route_prefix` configuration variable):

```
def get_static_path(request, name):
    from pyramid.config.views import StaticURLInfo
    registrations = StaticURLInfo()._get_registrations(request.registry)
    if not name.endswith('/'):
        name = name + '/'
    route_name = '__%s' % name
    for _url, spec, reg_route_name in registrations:
        print ':', reg_route_name
        if reg_route_name == route_name:
            return spec
```

In your case, it should work like this:

```
>>> get_static_path(request, 'static')
MyPkg:static/
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that is not dependent of the pyramid config, so it will not work if the file is moved. Imagine the case I don't know what the `path` is defined as, but I know there is a `static_view` with the name `static` for more encapsulation.

Comment: OK I get it now. See my extended answer.

Comment: Hum... Thx for the update. And indeed, I don't have access the the object at runtime, I only know the definition. I guess the best way for now would be to have a hard-coded value and to request them to add that "feature". Thanks for your help, I'll wait to see if other have some other insides too.

Comment: I've asked for an enhancement to Pyramid. For the effort and getting close to what I need, I'll accept this answer. No better suggestions came from the pyramid crew: https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/issues/440