# How do I find the physical path from a url in Pyramid and Python?

Tags: python, pyramid

I have a website built in Python's [Pyramid platform](http://www.pylonsproject.org/). I would like to convert a URL to a physical file in code.

For example, given the url:

```
/site/static/css/site.css
```

I would like to call some code to find the full physical path on the server, e.g.

```
full_file = server.mapPath('/site/static/css/site.css')
# full_file on linux / osx -> /www/sites/some_site/site/static/css/site.css
# full_file on windows -> c:\www\sites\some_site\site\static\css\site.css
```

Thanks! I can work around this by looking inside the site package I think but this seems better.

So the question is, does `server.mapPath` exist and what is it actually called?

Comment: this might have an answer for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289675/how-to-get-file-path-of-a-add-static-view-in-pyramid

Comment: Thanks, it seems at least related. I'll look closer tomorrow.